# Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph with mutually exclusive edges

Tags: graphs, time-complexity, bipartite-matching

**Problem**

I would to solve *Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem* **where some edges are mutually exclusive**.

**Example**

Left vertices: $a,b,c$

Right vertices: $x,y,z$

Edges: $(a,x),(a,y),(b,z),(c,y)$

Exlusive pairs: $(b,z)$ and $(c,y)$

Answer: *no perfect matching*

**Question**

Is the problem in *P* or *NP*?

**Solution Attempts**

I know that *Perfect Matching in Bipartite Graph Problem* is in *P*. But I cannot find a polynomial-time algorithms for the above version of this problem. I have also tried proving that it is *NP*, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $NP$ as $SAT$ can be polynomially reduced to this problem.

Let clauses be the left part vertexes, and literals be the right part vertexes. Draw an edge $(x,y)$ iff clause $x$ contains literal $y$. Finally, a pair of edges $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ will be exclusive iff $y_1$ corresponds to literal $a$ and $y_2$ corresponds to literal $\overline{a}$.